# Is it Common to use MEF with a config file for specifying a plugin path?

Tags: mef

I have heard that MEF reduces the need for creating config files, but if I have a few different plugin paths that vary depending on the client running the app, is it common and a good idea to have a config file that specifies the correct path.  I want to avoid looping through all the DLLs.

Answer (score 0):

Generally people have a well known plugin directory under the where the application is running from, i.e. \Extensions. However that said there isn't any particular reason you cannot do a configuration file for directories or exact extension assemblies.